# A java program that generates 100 random numbers

Tags: java

Can someone help me with this exercise? Write a program that generates 100 random numbers and stores each number into an integer array. For this program, you must meet the following technical requirements:  1)   In main, generate the 100 random numbers and store each in an array 2)  In main, ask the user to enter a number to see if it exists in the array 3) Write a function that takes the array and user number as input parameters and returns either true or false if the number does or does not exist in the array respectively  4)   In main, call this function appropriately and use the result to print out to the user if the number they provided is in the array

Comment: I don't think you should ask this type of homework question on stackoverflow.

Comment: I agree with @TangKe. The people in this community are much more receptive if you ask a more specific question, while also detailing what you've tried so far, and perhaps specific things you don't understand. This question is likely to be voted down and possibly even closed.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: A quick research on google will give you the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an extremely easy problem, and I will walk you through the steps, but not give you all the code because I know what it is like to be a beginner, and I learn visually by reading code.

1. You need an import for this, and that import is `java.util.Random`
2. You need an array to store it in, create an array with `int[]` and set it to a size of 100
3. You need a random object `Random rand = new Random()`
4. To generate 100 random integers and add them to an array you need to loop 100 times. Within that loop generate a number and add it to the array at index `i`
5. To check if a user inputted key exists once again loop through the array until a `arr[i] == key`, if it never finds a match it does not contain the number

If you have questions please leave a comment and I will try to be helpful

Comment: This is the >>right<< way to help someone with their homework.  Give them hints / ideas and get them to do the work for themselves.  (Maybe too many hints here for my liking, but worthy of upvotes anyhow.)

Comment: Thank you @Stephen C, yea I probably did drop to many hints. Some stuff I thought might not have been obvious to a beginner though

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random numbers like so:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int randomLessThan100 = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
int randomLessThan1000 = randomGenerator.nextInt(1000);
int randomBetween50And100 = randomGenerator.nextInt(49) + 51;
```